# How to load static field?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit, il, ilasm

I am generating a Type with static fields num1, num2, etc. via Reflection.Emit.

Now I do not know how to emit code which loads the contents of a static field in the generated type onto a static method's evaluation stack.
What I have tried so far is:

```
generator.Emit(Opcodes.Ldarg, 0);
generator.Emit(Opcodes.Ldfld, "num1");
```

But clearly this can not work, because it tries to load an instance field on 'this', which is not supplied to the static method.

**Which opcode should I use to access the static field?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Opcodes.Ldsfld`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldsfld.aspx)

So, assuming you have created num1 somewhere like `FieldBuilder num1 = ...` before, you can load it onto the stack via `generator.Emit(Opcodes.ldsfld, num1);`

Comment: And If I don't have FieldInfo instance but I have name, can I do it? (I've created Field but in another method).

Comment: Well, it would be tricky. You should at least pass along the TypeBuilder, so you can grab the FieldInfo from there.